# unable to open a modal with angular and ui.routes

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-router

I am trying to follow [this example](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-open-a-dialogmodal-at-a-certain-state) to show a bootstrap modal on a certain state. It works fine without a modal (so the state config should be ok). All needed dependencies (ie angular bootstrap) should be available.

when I do a `console.debug($stateParams)` before `$modal.open` I get the correct data, within the `$modal.open`-method however the stateParams from the last state are returned (the state I am coming from)

Any hints?

---

**EDIT**

the relevant state cfg:

```
.state('publications.view', {
    parent: 'publications.productSelection',
    url: '/{productSlug:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+}/{docID:[0-9]+}_{slug:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+}',
    onEnter: ['restFactory', '$state', '$stateParams', '$modal',
        function(restFactory, $state, $stateParams, $modal) {
            console.debug($stateParams.docID);
            $modal.open({

                templateUrl: 'partials/publication.html',
                resolve: {
                    publication: ['restFactory', '$stateParams',
                        function(restFactory, $stateParams) {
                            console.debug($state.params);
                            console.debug($stateParams);
                            return restFactory.view($stateParams.language, $stateParams.productSlug, $stateParams.docID);
                        }
                    ]
                },
                controller: ['$scope', '$sce', 'publication', '$rootScope',
                    function($scope, $sce, publication, $rootScope) {
                        $rootScope.pageTitle = publication.data.data.publication.Publication.title;
                        $scope.publication = $sce.trustAsHtml(publication.data.data.publication.Publication.content);
                    }
                ]
            });
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: How about some sample code?

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: nope .. well yes on a second thought.. the resolve path is missing the ID from the stateParams that is supposed to be retrieved, so the server returns an error, but no JS error or something. Everything looks good - it's just that the stateParams within the modal.open scope is not updated

Answer (score 1):

You can get around this issue by injecting the current $stateParams into the onEnter function, save them as state in some service, and inject that service instead into your modal resolves.

I am adapting the code from here: [Using ui-router with Bootstrap-ui modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24713242/using-ui-router-with-bootstrap-ui-modal)

```
.provider('modalState', function($stateProvider) {
    var modalState = {
        stateParams: {},
    };

    this.$get = function() {
        return modalState;
    };

    this.state = function(stateName, options) {
        var modalInstance;
        $stateProvider.state(stateName, {
            url: options.url,
            onEnter: function($modal, $state, $stateParams) {
                modalState.stateParams = $stateParams;
                modalInstance = $modal.open(options);
                modalInstance.result['finally'](function() {
                    modalInstance = null;
                    if ($state.$current.name === stateName) {
                        $state.go('^');
                    }
                });
            },
            onExit: function() {
                if (modalInstance) {
                    modalInstance.close();
                }
            }
        });
    };
})
```

Then in your app config section

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, modalStateProvider) {
    modalStateProvider.state('parent.child', {
        url: '/{id:[0-9]+}',
        templateUrl: 'views/child.html',
        controller: 'ChildCtrl',
        resolve: {
            role: function(Resource, modalState) {
                return Resource.get({id: modalState.stateParams.id}).$promise.then(function(data) {
                    return data;
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```