# Using Typescript ui-router provider for a modals

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Hello I need your help in making converting this excellent javascript code into typed ui-router.

## Question Section

**Question 1: So does a javascript callback equate the return of the instance of the typescript class?** Feel free to help me out if I am not going in the right direction.

Example of what I mean above:
In the code below I think that provider means a callback.
JavaScript

```
 var provider = this;
    this.$get = function() {
        return provider;
    }
```

I think but I am not sure that translates to typescript as:

```
   private _Service:any;
    public $get() { return this._Service; }

    constructor(private $stateProvider:any ) {
        this._Service = this;
    }
```

## Code Section

Here what I am trying to convert

```
.provider('modalState', function($stateProvider) {
    var provider = this;
    this.$get = function() {
        return provider;
    }
    this.state = function(stateName, options) {
        var modalInstance;
        $stateProvider.state(stateName, {
            url: options.url,
            onEnter: function($modal, $state) {
                modalInstance = $modal.open(options);
                modalInstance.result['finally'](function() {
                    modalInstance = null;
                    if ($state.$current.name === stateName) {
                        $state.go('^');
                    }
                });
            },
            onExit: function() {
                if (modalInstance) {
                    modalInstance.close();
                }
            }
        });
    };
})
```

which is excellent code found: [Using ui-router with Bootstrap-ui modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24713242/using-ui-router-with-bootstrap-ui-modal)

Here my attempt to convert it to typescript

```
class ModalService {

    private _Service:any;
    public $get() { return this._Service; }

    constructor(private $stateProvider:any ) {
        this._Service = this;
    }
    state(stateName:string, options:any ) : void {
        this.state =  (stateName, options)=> {
            var modalInstance;
            this.$stateProvider.state(stateName, {
                url: options.url,
                onEnter: ($modal, $state) => {
                    modalInstance = $modal.open(options);
                    modalInstance.result['finally']( ()=> {
                        modalInstance = null;
                        if ($state.$current.name === stateName) {
                            $state.go('^');
                        }
                    });
                },
                onExit: () => {
                    if (modalInstance) {
                        modalInstance.close();
                    }
                }
            });
        };


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out writting the functions above like this solve the issue and the modals are now working.

```
       public $get() {
                 return () => { return ModalService; }
             }
   constructor(private $stateProvider) {}
```

this is the equivalent after many hours of thinking. Very simple but I was stuck on it. Hope it helps other people.