# How to open ui-sref link in bootstrap modal

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

Before i start i want to to say many thanks in advance for your help. So, in my case i would like to open ui-sref link inside a bootstrap modal, meaning display the ui-sref in the modal. Below my code:

```
<ul class="friend-list">
          <li class="bounceInDown" style="margin-left:5px;" ng-repeat="conversation in ctrl.conversations" ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="user-app.inbox.messages({ convID: conversation.id })">
              <a  class="clearfix" style="cursor: pointer;">
                  <img ng-src="{{conversation.author.image}}" alt="user and company profil image for messages" class="img-circle" style="margin-right: 15px;"></img>
                  <div class="friend-name">
                      <strong>{{conversation.author.name}}</strong>
                  </div>
            </div>
      </ul>
```

> This ui-sref link will open the column that contain the messages.

Comment: When you say open the column, do you mean you would have a nested view state within the modal, or will the column open into a new state outside of the modal?

Comment: @khaled did you look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24713242/using-ui-router-with-bootstrap-ui-modal

Comment: Thans a lot for the link i will check it !!